# AngularJs Restangular get in interval

Tags: angularjs, intervals, restangular

I must check data in API every for example 5sec and pass to array which is binding to html. When I invoke function in $interval like this:
$interval(refreshData, 5000);

It works, but destroy any other action which I doing for example close dropdowns etc.

What is the best way for create GET in specific interval?

Comment: why do you need to make an API call every 5 sec? every call means request right?.. it will be a heavy burden to your server if you do this

Comment: backend give me notifications, which i must show i html, but I don't know when new data appear in api so I must check by doing request to API. Let say i can do request in every 60sec

Comment: Why not use real-time ? you might wanna check pusherJs https://pusher.com/ or sockets http://socket.io/ . Its much better implementation rather than doing your polling method.

Its like publish and subscribe methodology

Comment: Ok, but why any action is canceled wheny function is invoke (like collapse dropdown list, or break slider)

Answer (score -1):

I saw that in Firefox is ok, only Google Chrome,cancel any actions like coil selected dropdown list etc. when I load data to variable in promise. Anyone have idea why it happen?